# Sum of values of nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a sum of all values of nested dictionary with variable number of elements: For example:-

```
a = {'val1': 3, 'val2': 4, 'val3': {'val4': 2, 'val5': 1}, 'val6': {'val7': 9, 'val8': {'val6': 43}}}
```

Let say I have a dictionary like above.
And the output I want for this is :

```
3+4+2+1+9+43 = 62
```

I have tried this but I know it will not work:

```
dict_sum = 0
for k, v in a.items():

    if isinstance(v,dict):
        dict_sum += sum(v.values())
    else:
        dict_sum += v
```

But it will not work work for dictionary with multiple nested dictionaries. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is using recursion.

For example:

```
data = {'val1': 3, 'val2': 4, 'val3': {'val4': 2, 'val5': 1}, 'val6': {'val7': 9, 'val8': {'val6': 43}}}

def get_sum(data):
    s = 0
    for _, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            s += get_sum(v)
        else:
            s += v
    return s
print(get_sum(data))  # --> 62
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
a = {'val1': 3, 'val2': 4, 'val3': {'val4': 2, 'val5': 1}, 'val6': {'val7': 9, 'val8': {'val6': 43}}}

def DeepSum(data):
    return sum([x if isinstance(x, int) else DeepSum(x) for x in data.values() ]) 

DeepSum(a)
```

Comment: It is giving error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in DeepSum
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <listcomp>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in DeepSum
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: @Markus using online compiler https://onlinegdb.com/B1qDEy81P

Comment: But, I think it should work for offline as well. What if I am working offline and unable to use this function.

Comment: @Markus online compiler proves that the code is correct, it must be something with your machine

Comment: I have taught about it, but I'm using same 3.8.3. that code is very simple, I don't know why it would not run